# lookup datasource in context every time, Is it right?

Tags: java, datasource, jndi

In my application i configured more than one datasource (for diff databases). Whenever user sends a request depends upon user category i need to look up for the respective datasource in the context and get a connection from that datasource to execute queries which are assigned to that user. Is it right way to achieve my requirement? I am using tomcat 6, struts 1.3. The databases may be oracle or mysql or both.

Give me an optimized solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: and make sure your datasource uses a connection pool e.g. c3p0

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can create a [Service Locator](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/servicelocator-137181.html) where you can cache every JNDI objects retrieved. That way, you don't have to invoke the JNDI lookup every time but pull out from the cache.

Comment: If neglect the performance impact of multiple call,is there any other side effect of this method?(like creating duplicate data sources)?

Comment: The container will complain if a duplicate datasource is created. This method just mitigate the constant hitting of JNDI lookup.